# Cucumber: Testing for secondary request or response headers

Tags: cucumber

Using Cuke to test java web app running through selenium driver.  On load the page makes some external requests for tracking purposes (omniture, doubleclick).  How would I go about inspecting the requests that the browser makes so that I could verify for example that the following URL was requested by the browser during page load?

```
http://doubleclick.net/<whatever>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have come up with a different (or the same) solution by now... I am testing my reporting library by sending the various requests to my web application and storing those requests to then inspect in my cucumber tests.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually working on a ruby on rails project now but I never did go anywhere with this one.  At the time I was just playing with Cucumber to see if it would work for us.